# change first loader to windows instead of ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

Currently I have Windows and Ubuntu installed and dual boot is working fine.

However the dual boot is loading via GRUB, but I want it to load from Windows' bootloader as I want to enable bitlocker.

How can I hide grub and show Windows' bootloader when I press the power button?

Comment: its not duplicate of Uninstall Grub and use Windows bootloader. as i want to retain ubuntu

Comment: You may want to just install grub to a flash drive or two and use that to boot when you want Ubuntu. You just use MBR, so you can still use flash drive for data or backup. Using EasyBCD may work but not sure with bitlocker.